# How can i call query with parameter and then populate using dynamoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamoose

```
 var added = await Feature.scan("parentId").eq(baseIds).exec()
        .then(function (add) {
            return add.populate({
               path: 'parentId',
              model: 'Feature'
             })
           })
```

> I have a server already setup working with dynamoose. I want to make a query on basic of a value field and then populate but i am not able to achieve it with the solutions in the dynamoose api docs.Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Dynamoose documentation](https://dynamoosejs.com/api#modelpopulateoptions):

```
Dog.scan().exec()
  .then(function(dogs) {
    return Promise.all(dogs.map(function(dog) {
      return dog.populate({
        path: 'parent',
        model: 'Dog'
      });
    }));
  })
  .then(function(dogs) {
    console.log(dogs);
  });
```

Since scan gives you an array of objects, you have to populate each item individually and wait for all those promises to succeed.